# Need help translating this title and signature? (Characters identified: 古堂)

Tags: translation, characters, meaning-in-context, character-identification

Can someone help me with what this says?

[image: signature]

(see also: [full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5xII.jpg))

I've tried Google image search, and even looking for different signatures, but no luck so far.

Comment: @zyy  tried but it wont rotate correctly ones I upload it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is the name/signature of the author. Note that usually it's not the original family name, because traditional Chinese people styled themselves some particular names or titles apart from the given name from the family.

In your case it looks like "古堂" and it's not a famous name to me at least...

=== Update ===

Regarding the signature, 堂 usually means "hall" or a large room used for specific purpose. I'm not 100% sure the first character is "古", which means ancient/old. Although some people did use the title of his unique place to present himself, yet "ancient hall" here as a place is kind of neutral to me to be used by a famous people...

The seals (which is very blurry in your photo) in Chinese painting or artworks do not have to be the name/title of the author. In some cases it can also be the name/title of a place, short phrases, etc. as long as it's identical to the author.

Comment: Thank you, this will help in finding out more about the author.

Comment: could it be that the name of the painting is 古堂 instead of the artists?

Comment: Less likely. Because 堂 usually means "hall" or a large room used for specific purpose.  I'm not 100% sure the first character is "古", which means ancient/old. Obviously the drawing was more about an outdoor place/activity than a hall or a room...

Comment: the stroke is strange. I google "ナロ堂" (Japanese) but have no luck either.